# Add a column based on existing column strings

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data_frame(ended= c("14/11/2016 13:37", "14/11/2016 13:37",
"14/11/2016 13:47", "14/11/2016 13:51", "14/11/2016 13:51"), 
satisfactionLevel = c("Very dissatisfied", "Very satisfied",
"Satisfied", "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied",
"Very satisfied"))
```

I want to add a column `weight` that takes the following values

```
weightScores <- data_frame(weight = c(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1))
```

where

- 0 is assigned when satisfactionLevel = "Very dissatisfied",
- 1 when satisfactionLevel = "Very satisfied",
- 0.75 when satisfactionLevel = "Satisfied",
- 0.5 when "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` solution (with `case_when`):

```
library(dplyr)
# Using OPs data
data <- data %>%
    mutate(weight = case_when(
         satisfactionLevel == "Very dissatisfied" ~ 0,
         satisfactionLevel == "Very satisfied" ~ 1,
         satisfactionLevel == "Satisfied" ~ 0.75,
         satisfactionLevel == "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied" ~ 0.5))
```

Comment: Elegant solution, exactly what I was hoping for. +1 from me

Comment: @Greconomist happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you include a "satisfactionLevel" column in your weightScores dataframe, you should be able to use

```
merge(data, weightScores, by="satisfactionLevel")
```